How to stick a counter top washbasin onto a wood surface
I have a countertop wash basin that I need to fix onto a wood countertop in the bathroom. The base of the basin is quite small and I want to be sure that it doesn't move around. I guess that the pipe-work for water drainage will hold it to a certain extent but do I need to use silicone or some kind of glue?
Thanks for any suggestions.

Welcome. Please take the [tour]. "Thanks" comments are discouraged.

A wash basin over wood is generally not recommended, however a ring of caulk or plumbers putty may be used to seal to the counter.
Then you need to be sure you have a drain assembly suited for Non-Overflow vessel sinks.  These have a little larger washer supplied for under the counter. Once installed the drain and tailpiece will hold the sink to the counter.

I agree with RMDman that the hardware should handle this for you. If you do think you need something more substantial to make it more solid, my go-to for things like this is clear silicone. It's fairly strong, somewhat removable, and doesn't look like crap if your bead is imperfect because the color of the surfaces behind transmits through.
That said, it should really be hidden. Virtually none should show outside the sink basin. You'd apply a ring to the underside of the basin, set it in place, and finger or tool any squeeze-out away so you're left with an inconspicuous cove. This is the same approach I take with toilets, and it almost disappears, leaving the clean line of the fixture rather than a goopy line of caulk.
This assumes you prefer a bowl-on-table appearance, and not a fixture-growing-out-of-surface appearance. Some prefer a more welded look. I don't. I like something reminiscent of a still life image of a bowl or cask resting on a surface, but with a seal to prevent gunk from becoming slime underneath it.
